# как выровнять все элементы li по центру в ul

Tags: html, ul

Есть список `ul`. В нём `li` в виде плиточек. `li` задано `float:left;`. Соответственно все `li` расположены горизонтально. Ширина `li` задана в *процентах*, высота задана в *px*.

Если изменить размер браузера, то те плитки которые не вмещаются переносятся на следующую строку и справа остаётся пустое место. Из этого появилась потребность выровнять все в `ul` по центру. Если задавать `margin`, то ничего не работает...
Есть какие-то варианты?

```css
ul li {
 list-style-type: none !important;
}

.feed-main {
 width: 100%;
/*  height: calc(100% - 21px); */
 padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px !important;
}

.feed-main ul{
 width: 100%;
/*  height: 100%; */
    background: #FFF;
    padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px !important;
}

.feed-main ul li.link-block{
 width: 13.44%;
 height: 123px;
  float: left;
 background: #ECECEC;
 margin: 0 5px 10px 5px !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="feed-main">
<ul>
 <li class="link-block"></li>
 <li class="link-block"></li>
 <li class="link-block"></li>
 <li class="link-block"></li>
 <li class="link-block"></li>
 <li class="link-block"></li>
 <li class="link-block"></li>
 <li class="link-block"></li>
 <li class="link-block"></li>
 <li class="link-block"></li>
 <li class="link-block"></li>
 <li class="link-block"></li>
 <li class="link-block"></li>
 <li class="link-block"></li>
 <li class="link-block"></li>
 <li class="link-block"></li>
 <li class="link-block"></li>
 <li class="link-block"></li>
 <li class="link-block"></li>
 <li class="link-block"></li>
 <li class="link-block"></li>
 <li class="link-block"></li>
 <li class="link-block"></li>
 <li class="link-block"></li>
 <li class="link-block"></li>
 <li class="link-block"></li>
 <li class="link-block"></li>
 <li class="link-block"></li>
 <li class="link-block"></li>
 <li class="link-block"></li>
 <li class="link-block"></li>
 <li class="link-block"></li>
 <li class="link-block"></li>
 <li class="link-block"></li>
 <li class="link-block"></li>
 <li class="link-block"></li>
 <li class="link-block"></li>
 <li class="link-block"></li>
 <li class="link-block"></li>
 <li class="link-block"></li>
 <li class="link-block"></li>
 <li class="link-block"></li>
 <li class="link-block"></li>
 <li class="link-block"></li>
 <li class="link-block"></li>
 <li class="link-block"></li>
 <li class="link-block"></li>
 <li class="link-block"></li>
 <li class="link-block"></li>

 <li class="link-block"></li>
 <li class="link-block"></li>
 <li class="link-block"></li>
 <li class="link-block"></li>
 <li class="link-block"></li>
 <li class="link-block"></li>
 <li class="link-block"></li>
 <li class="link-block"></li>
 <li class="link-block"></li>
 <li class="link-block"></li>
 <li class="link-block"></li>
 <li class="link-block"></li>
 <li class="link-block"></li>
 <li class="link-block"></li>
 <li class="link-block"></li>
 <li class="link-block"></li>
 <li class="link-block"></li>
 <li class="link-block"></li>
 <li class="link-block"></li>
 <li class="link-block"></li>
 <li class="link-block"></li>
 <li class="link-block"></li>
 <li class="link-block"></li>
 <li class="link-block"></li>
 <li class="link-block"></li>
 <li class="link-block"></li>
 <li class="link-block"></li>
 <li class="link-block"></li>
 <li class="link-block"></li>
 <li class="link-block"></li>
 <li class="link-block"></li>
 <li class="link-block"></li>
 <li class="link-block"></li>
 <li class="link-block"></li>
 <li class="link-block"></li>
 <li class="link-block"></li>
 <li class="link-block"></li>
 <li class="link-block"></li>
 <li class="link-block"></li>
 <li class="link-block"></li>
 <li class="link-block"></li>
 <li class="link-block"></li>
 <li class="link-block"></li>
 <li class="link-block"></li>
 <li class="link-block"></li>
 <li class="link-block"></li>
 <li class="link-block"></li>
 <li class="link-block"></li>
 <li class="link-block"></li>

</ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

```css
ul{
  display:table;
  margin:auto;
}
li{
  display:table-cell;
  text-align:center;
  padding:3px 10px;
}
a{
  display:table-cell;
  valign:bottom;
}
```

```html
<ul> 
   <li><a href="">Ссылка #1</a></li>
   <li><a href="">Ссылка #2</a></li>
   <li><a href="">Ссылка с длинным текстом</a></li>
   <li><a href="">Ссыдка обычная</a></li>
</ul>
```

[Demo CodePen](http://codepen.io/maximvelin/pen/EKJqXz?editors=110) сожмите экран и посмотрите как ведёт себя эта вёрстка

Comment: Добавил в шапку ul который у меня. Сделал как подсказали вы и у меня все li слились в одну строку.

Comment: а сколько li у вас ?

Comment: ну скажем.изначально будет 77. При прокрутке будет добавляться 49. Вообще кол-во li зависит от кол-ва записей в бд - это в будущем. Ведь для формирования li нужны будут данные которые в бд будут.

Comment: Заметил. Я добавил ещё 7 li и теперь начало больше подгружаться li при прокрутке.

Comment: тогда моё решение не для вашего примера , вам подойдёт Flat вёрстка , почитайте о этом виде

Comment: Хм. почитал вроде как... но того что могло бы мне помочь не увидел. Сайт делаю изначально в таком виде...

Answer (score 1):

```css
ul li {
 list-style-type: none !important;
}

.feed-main {
 width: 100%;
/*  height: calc(100% - 21px); */
 padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px !important;
}

.feed-main ul{
 width: 100%;
/*  height: 100%; */
    background: #FFF;
    padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px !important;
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: wrap;
    justify-content: center;
}

.feed-main ul li.link-block{
 width: 13.44%;
 height: 123px;
  float: left;
 background: #ECECEC;
 margin: 0 5px 10px 5px !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="feed-main">
<ul>
 <li class="link-block"></li>
 <li class="link-block"></li>
 <li class="link-block"></li>
 <li class="link-block"></li>
 <li class="link-block"></li>
 <li class="link-block"></li>
 <li class="link-block"></li>
 <li class="link-block"></li>
 <li class="link-block"></li>
 <li class="link-block"></li>
 <li class="link-block"></li>
 <li class="link-block"></li>
 <li class="link-block"></li>
 <li class="link-block"></li>
 <li class="link-block"></li>
 <li class="link-block"></li>
 <li class="link-block"></li>
 <li class="link-block"></li>
 <li class="link-block"></li>
 <li class="link-block"></li>
 <li class="link-block"></li>
 <li class="link-block"></li>
 <li class="link-block"></li>
 <li class="link-block"></li>
 <li class="link-block"></li>
 <li class="link-block"></li>
 <li class="link-block"></li>
 <li class="link-block"></li>
 <li class="link-block"></li>
 <li class="link-block"></li>
 <li class="link-block"></li>
 <li class="link-block"></li>
 <li class="link-block"></li>
 <li class="link-block"></li>
 <li class="link-block"></li>
 <li class="link-block"></li>
 <li class="link-block"></li>
 <li class="link-block"></li>
 <li class="link-block"></li>
 <li class="link-block"></li>
 <li class="link-block"></li>
 <li class="link-block"></li>
 <li class="link-block"></li>
 <li class="link-block"></li>
 <li class="link-block"></li>
 <li class="link-block"></li>
 <li class="link-block"></li>
 <li class="link-block"></li>
 <li class="link-block"></li>

 <li class="link-block"></li>
 <li class="link-block"></li>
 <li class="link-block"></li>
 <li class="link-block"></li>
 <li class="link-block"></li>
 <li class="link-block"></li>
 <li class="link-block"></li>
 <li class="link-block"></li>
 <li class="link-block"></li>
 <li class="link-block"></li>
 <li class="link-block"></li>
 <li class="link-block"></li>
 <li class="link-block"></li>
 <li class="link-block"></li>
 <li class="link-block"></li>
 <li class="link-block"></li>
 <li class="link-block"></li>
 <li class="link-block"></li>
 <li class="link-block"></li>
 <li class="link-block"></li>
 <li class="link-block"></li>
 <li class="link-block"></li>
 <li class="link-block"></li>
 <li class="link-block"></li>
 <li class="link-block"></li>
 <li class="link-block"></li>
 <li class="link-block"></li>
 <li class="link-block"></li>
 <li class="link-block"></li>
 <li class="link-block"></li>
 <li class="link-block"></li>
 <li class="link-block"></li>
 <li class="link-block"></li>
 <li class="link-block"></li>
 <li class="link-block"></li>
 <li class="link-block"></li>
 <li class="link-block"></li>
 <li class="link-block"></li>
 <li class="link-block"></li>
 <li class="link-block"></li>
 <li class="link-block"></li>
 <li class="link-block"></li>
 <li class="link-block"></li>
 <li class="link-block"></li>
 <li class="link-block"></li>
 <li class="link-block"></li>
 <li class="link-block"></li>
 <li class="link-block"></li>
 <li class="link-block"></li>

</ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Вы такого результата ожидаете?

```css
ul li {
    list-style-type: none !important;
}

.feed-main {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px !important;
    text-align: center;
}

.feed-main ul{
    width: 100%;
    background: #FFF;
    padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px !important;
}

.feed-main ul li.link-block{
    width: 13.44%;
    height: 123px;
    display: inline-block;
    background: #ECECEC;
    margin: 0 5px 10px 5px !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="feed-main">
    <ul>
     <li class="link-block"></li>
     <li class="link-block"></li>
     <li class="link-block"></li>
     <li class="link-block"></li>
     <li class="link-block"></li>
     <li class="link-block"></li>
     <li class="link-block"></li>
     <li class="link-block"></li>
     <li class="link-block"></li>
     <li class="link-block"></li>
     <li class="link-block"></li>
     <li class="link-block"></li>
     <li class="link-block"></li>
     <li class="link-block"></li>
     <li class="link-block"></li>
     <li class="link-block"></li>
     <li class="link-block"></li>
     <li class="link-block"></li>
     <li class="link-block"></li>
     <li class="link-block"></li>
     <li class="link-block"></li>
     <li class="link-block"></li>
     <li class="link-block"></li>
     <li class="link-block"></li>
     <li class="link-block"></li>
     <li class="link-block"></li>
     <li class="link-block"></li>
     <li class="link-block"></li>
     <li class="link-block"></li>
     <li class="link-block"></li>
     <li class="link-block"></li>
     <li class="link-block"></li>
     <li class="link-block"></li>
     <li class="link-block"></li>
     <li class="link-block"></li>
     <li class="link-block"></li>
     <li class="link-block"></li>
     <li class="link-block"></li>
     <li class="link-block"></li>
     <li class="link-block"></li>
     <li class="link-block"></li>
     <li class="link-block"></li>
     <li class="link-block"></li>
     <li class="link-block"></li>
     <li class="link-block"></li>
     <li class="link-block"></li>
     <li class="link-block"></li>
     <li class="link-block"></li>
     <li class="link-block"></li>
     
     <li class="link-block"></li>
     <li class="link-block"></li>
     <li class="link-block"></li>
     <li class="link-block"></li>
     <li class="link-block"></li>
     <li class="link-block"></li>
     <li class="link-block"></li>
     <li class="link-block"></li>
     <li class="link-block"></li>
     <li class="link-block"></li>
     <li class="link-block"></li>
     <li class="link-block"></li>
     <li class="link-block"></li>
     <li class="link-block"></li>
     <li class="link-block"></li>
     <li class="link-block"></li>
     <li class="link-block"></li>
     <li class="link-block"></li>
     <li class="link-block"></li>
     <li class="link-block"></li>
     <li class="link-block"></li>
     <li class="link-block"></li>
     <li class="link-block"></li>
     <li class="link-block"></li>
     <li class="link-block"></li>
     <li class="link-block"></li>
     <li class="link-block"></li>
     <li class="link-block"></li>
     <li class="link-block"></li>
     <li class="link-block"></li>
     <li class="link-block"></li>
     <li class="link-block"></li>
     <li class="link-block"></li>
     <li class="link-block"></li>
     <li class="link-block"></li>
     <li class="link-block"></li>
     <li class="link-block"></li>
     <li class="link-block"></li>
     <li class="link-block"></li>
     <li class="link-block"></li>
     <li class="link-block"></li>
     <li class="link-block"></li>
     <li class="link-block"></li>
     <li class="link-block"></li>
     <li class="link-block"></li>
     <li class="link-block"></li>
     <li class="link-block"></li>
     <li class="link-block"></li>
     <li class="link-block"></li>
     
    </ul>
   </div>
```

Comment: Да, то что нужно.
Но появилась другая проблема. У меня при прокрутке страницы в конец ul добавляется 49 li-ев при помощи JS. li те которые написаны изначально отображаются как вы сделали, но те элементы которые добавляет JS они не отображаются так...

Comment: выкладывайте всё на https://jsfiddle.net/ (точнее не всё, а только те куски кода, которые имеют отношение :)

Comment: выкладывать с JS-ом?

Comment: вот как-то так. прокрутите ниже чуть и увидите. https://jsfiddle.net/Tsyklop/8kkf3puf/show/

Comment: насколько я понимаю, тут проблема в том, что jquery создаёт новый DOM-элемент `<li>` уже после того, как были применены стили. а попробуйте не создавать его через `appent('<li>...</li>')`, а клонировать `$('li.link-block').clone().appendTo('.feed-main ul')`.

Comment: сделал так, и теперь при прокрутке страницы она зависает... сделал так: *$('li.link-block:first').clone().appendTo('.feed-main ul');* всё подгружается...но всё равно криво добавляется.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй через Flex:

```
.feed-main ul{
    width: 100%;
    background: #FFF;
    padding: 5px !important;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: space-around;
}
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Уверен, автор вопроса был бы благодарен за ваш экспертный комментарий к приведенному выше коду.